# SQL get the min and max value of a column in a dataset with a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I have no idea how to execute this problem with a simple query.
Assuming this table is named **Records**

```
RecordId | CreatedDate | ModifiedDate
1        | 11/07/2020  | 9/08/2020
1        | 03/06/2020  | 12/07/2020
2        | 06/05/2020  | 11/06/2020
3        | 12/12/2019  | 23/04/2020
3        | 05/01/2020  | 11/04/2020
```

And what I want is get the oldest CreatedDate and latest ModifiedDate per record id.
My result set should be something like this.

```
RecordId | CreatedDate | ModifiedDate
1        | 03/06/2020  | 9/08/2020
2        | 06/05/2020  | 11/06/2020
3        | 05/01/2020  | 23/04/2020
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT R.RECORDID,MIN(R.CREATEDDATE),MAX(R.MODIFIEDDATE)
FROM RECORDS AS R
GROUP BY R.RECORDID
```